# 'in <string>' requires string as left operand not list

Tags: python

i have my input file like this:

```
>seq_1
ATTAGACCTG
>seq_2
CCTGCCGGAA
>seq_3
AGACCTGCCG
>seq_4
GCCGGAATAC
```

I have writen this code to get common superstring:

```
from itertools import permutations

def parse_fasta (lines):
descs = []
seqs = []
data = ''
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        if data:
            seqs.append(data)
            data = ''
        descs.append(line)
    else:
        data += line.rstrip('\r\n')
seqs.append(data)
return descs, seqs

descriptions, sequences = parse_fasta(open('D:\python\input.fasta', 'r').read().split('\n'))

def solve(*strings):
"""
Given a list of strings, return the shortest string that contains them all.
"""
return min((simplify(p) for p in permutations(strings)), key=len)

def prefixes(s):
"""
Return a list of all the prefixes of the given string (including itself),
in ascending order (from shortest to longest).
"""
return [s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s))]
return [(i,s[:i+1]) for i in range(len(s))][::-1]

def simplify(strings):
"""
Given a list of strings, concatenate them wile removing overlaps between
successive elements.
"""
ret = ''
for s in strings:
    if s in ret:
        continue
    for i, prefix in reversed(list(enumerate(prefixes(s)))):
        if ret.endswith(prefix):
            ret += s[i+1:]
            break
    else:
        ret += s
return ret

print solve(sequences)
```

I am getting the error as shown in title. when i am giving

```
print solve('ATTAGACCTG','CCTGCCGGAA','AGACCTGCCG','GCCGGAATAC')
```

I am getting the correct output. but I want to give my input as the file shown in the program. And want this result:

```
ATTAGACCTGCCGGAATAC
```

Comment: Please, fix the identation of the code.

Comment: You have two successive returns in `prefixes`. That won't work. Also, could you explain the algorithm you want to implement?

Comment: I removed one return statement but still getting same error

Comment: Explain the algorithm and I'll take a look.

Comment: explanation is given in the code.

Comment: is this a http://rosalind.info problem.  If so, what is the link to the problem so that i can give it a look.  If it is take a look at this github linked file 
https://github.com/mtarbit/Rosalind-Problems/blob/master/e025-long.py

Comment: its the genome assembly problem but I want to do the way I have coded.

Comment: I have 50 seq as input .. I dont want to enter them manually.